# Google play developer console, howto add external linked project?

Tags: google-api, google-play

I am trying to use the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) to automate APK submissions via a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

The question is, how do I give my project (and my service account) OUTSIDE of this play account, API access to manage apps?

**Use case and example:**

Each of my clients have their own Google Play account where their app(s) live.  Apps used to be all in one big account, but for many reasons (Google pushing to separate being the highest) they are now broken up.

Lets say there are 2 google play accounts, `A` and `B`.  Traditionally, each of these accounts grant my physical email user (`me@gmail.com`) "Release manager" access to each of their accounts. My email/user is OUTSIDE of account `A` and `B`. This works fine.

I now want to automate this process.  I go to the [developer API console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=1) for `me@gmail.com`, enable "Google Play Android Developer API" and create an oAuth2 service account (gives it an email of `blah@developer.gserviceaccount.com`).  I then tell clients to go into accounts (`A` and `B`) and tell them to give `blah@developer.gserviceaccount.com` "Release manager" access.

I make an API call and get

> The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console

API calls do work if I go into account `A` and account `B` under Google Play Developer Console > Settings > API access, and make Services accounts for each.  It makes an entry in "User accounts & Rights" for this service user's email, then links a SINGLE project ID that MUST be owned by the Google play account.

**Questions:**

- How do I add a service account that is NOT defined in Settings > API access?
- Why is there only ability to link 1 project?

You can give outside email addresses full perms, but you can NOT give an outside service account email API access?  The current design is not any more secure. In fact, it seems to go against most of the benefit of the API, and against the grain of account isolation that Google has been pushing.

Comment: I know it's been a while. I have a similar problem. Did you found a solution?